# Invalid gopkg.in package and rev in

Tags: pants

When attempting to build with Pants, I am seeing the following error:

```
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/pants/contrib/go/tasks/go_fetch.py", line 154, in _transitive_download_remote_libs
    all_known_addresses)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/pants/contrib/go/tasks/go_fetch.py", line 105, in _transitive_download_remote_libs
    fetcher.fetch(go_remote_lib.import_path, dest=tmp_fetch_root, rev=go_remote_lib.rev)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/pants/contrib/go/subsystems/fetchers.py", line 437, in fetch
    github_root, github_rev = self._map_import_path(import_path, rev)
  File "/Users/chad/.cache/pants/setup/bootstrap/pants.mbFDa8/install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pants/util/memo.py", line 95, in memoize
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/pants/contrib/go/subsystems/fetchers.py", line 454, in _map_import_path
    raise self.FetchError('Invalid gopkg.in package and rev in: {}'.format(import_path))

Exception message: Invalid gopkg.in package and rev in: gopkg.in/amz.v1/aws
```

Here is the contents of my BUILD file:

```
# Auto-generated by pants!
# To re-generate run: `pants buildgen.go --materialize --remote`

go_remote_library(rev='v1')
```

Looking into the code, I see that the error comes from a failure to match a regex in fetchers.py, [on line 453](https://github.com/pantsbuild/pants/blob/ed5badda3d518c869aa22d6401f604aa864fcfc4/contrib/go/src/python/pants/contrib/go/subsystems/fetchers.py#L453).

I am running Pants version 0.0.59 on Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)

Comment: It says that build file was automatically generated.  Please tell us about the input from which it was generated.

Answer (score 1):

Noting that [@Huckphin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38009/huckphin) stumbled on a bug here in `pantsbuild.pants<=0.0.59`. He filed an [issue](https://github.com/pantsbuild/pants/issues/2581) and now things are fixed up for handling `gopkg.in` remote import paths that point to sub-packages in the remote repo.  The fix will be released with the regular Friday release on 11/20/2015 in `0.0.60`.